# OpenID error: No_Oauth_Token unauthorized_client

Tags: oauth2, authentication, open-id-connect

I am following [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5) to implement an external authentication provider.

So far I was able to be redirected to their site, authenticate there and be sent back to SF. However, when I am sent back to SF, I am always landing on the page that simply says "Problem logging in":

[image]

The URL gives a little bit more info:

> salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=unauthorized_client&ProviderId=0SO3N0000004DPb

However, my googling skills did not help me with this "unauthorized_client" error.

Here is my Auth. Provider setup:

[image]

When I inspected the network tab in browser console, here's what happens:

1. From Auth. Provider it redirects me to `myorg.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/itsme?code=SOME_CODE&state=SOME_STATE`
2. The next one shows that same Request URL with code 302(Moved Temporarily) and it redirects me to `myorg.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=unauthorized_client&ProviderId=0SO3N0000004DPb`

My next guess was that I need to handle it in "AutocreatedRegHandler1587022317937" class, so to see what happens in there I have simply put something like this in the beginning of both `createUser()` and `updateUser()` methods:

```
Custom_log__c cl = new Custom_log__c();
cl.Message__c = 'portalId: ' + portalId + '\n\ndata: ' + data;
cl.Description__c = 'SSO UU';
insert cl;
```

That custom log is just an object with a couple text fields, but no new logs are being created, so this class never gets called. I have also tried enabling debug logs for "Execute Registration As" user, but alas, no logs either.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your service (`itsme.services`) is a standard [OpenID Connect endpoint](https://failforward.tech). As a relying party, SF supports OpenID Connect [out of the box](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hi @identigral, thanks for your response, but that's exactly the doc that I was following

Comment: Registration Handler is optional..but your error message happens before it hits the handler. You posted fragments of HTTP messages but it's not enough to troubleshoot. Please update your post with a complete trace (all HTTP requests/responses, headers + body). You could give [this test app](https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/) a shot to see how this should work with SF as Authorization Server. It's the inverse of your scenario but all the messages are the same.

Comment: I'm getting the same landing page error but my URL is different "/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=Remote_Error&ErrorDescription=invalid_request"